# Data Import from 1 DB to other DB, phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Hy all!
i have 2 databases on phpmyadmin
DB-A have less data
DB-B have more data
both databases have same tables
i want to import all data from DB-B to DB-A, i just want to import data with constraints, i dont want to overwrite any data or delete any existing data in DB-A.
can anyone plz guide me how can i do it.

Comment: Is there any Auto Number Column?

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto-increment columns in the DB-A please turn off the auto-increment (in MSSQL you can set this to be off, not sure about other DBs).

Then you could do an anti join between tables in DB-B and DB-A. Something like:

```
insert into DB-A.table
select b.* 
from DB-B.table b left join DB-A a on a.pk = b.pk
WHERE a.pk is null
```

Please remember order the tables you do this to by the foreign key constraints, similar to the way you would drop tables and not get constraint errors.

More info on anti joins: https://mode.com/blog/anti-join-examples/